# How to format Code in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-formatting

Is it possible to format all of the code in Visual Studio Code to my specific prefrences.

I want the formatter to leave a space before any brackets and go onto a new line before and after any curly braces.

I do not want the formatter to format the code in any other way. I only want to format the code in these two ways.

This format should be applied automatically to any code I write after I hit save.

I have looked online and found the Prettier extension. Hovewer, this extension also formats the code in many other ways. I only want the code formatter to leave a space before any brackets and go onto a new line before and after any curly braces.

Comment: it depends on the language/extensions you have

Comment: Do you want code formatting for Javascript? Or python? Or ... which language do you want formatting for?

Comment: I want code formatting for all languages, only to leave a space before any brackets and go onto a new line before and after any curly braces.